# AngularJS application with RequireJS gives "use strict" error in Safari & Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, requirejs

So I have overtaken a pretty comprehensive AngularJS application that uses RequireJS to modularize and also uses Grunt(RequireJS optimizer plugin) to compile the code and minifiy it.

The minified code gives me the following error in Firefox:

*"SyntaxError: in strict mode code, functions may be declared only at top level or immediately within another function"*

And in Safari:

*"SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement."*

Here is the first part of the code:

```
function(e, t, n) {
"use strict";

function r(e) {
    return function() {
        var t = arguments[0],
            n = "[" + (e ? e + ":" : "") + t + "] ",
            r = arguments[1],
            i = arguments,
            s = function(e) {
                return typeof e == "function" ? e.toString().replace(/ \{[\s\S]*$/, "") : typeof e == "undefined" ? "undefined" : typeof e != "string" ? JSON.stringify(e) : e
            },
            o, u;
        o = n + r.replace(/\{\d+\}/g, function(e) {
            var t = +e.slice(1, -1),
                n;
            if (t + 2 < i.length) return n = i[t + 2], typeof n == "function" ? n.toString().replace(/ ?\{[\s\S]*$/, "") : typeof n == "undefined" ? "undefined" : typeof n != "string" ? ht(n) : n;
            return e
        }), o = o + "\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.29/" + (e ? e + "/" : "") + t;
        for (u = 2; u < arguments.length; u++) o = o + (u == 2 ? "?" : "&") + "p" + (u - 2) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(s(arguments[u]));
        return new Error(o)
    }
}

function E(e) {
    if (e == null || z(e)) return !1;
    var t = e.length;
    return e.nodeType === 1 && t ? !0 : j(e) || q(e) || t === 0 || typeof t == "number" && t > 0 && t - 1 in e
}

function S(e, t, n) {
    var r;
    if (e)
        if (R(e))
            for (r in e) r != "prototype" && r != "length" && r != "name" && (!e.hasOwnProperty || e.hasOwnProperty(r)) && t.call(n, e[r], r);
        else if (q(e) || E(e))
        for (r = 0; r < e.length; r++) t.call(n, e[r], r);
    else if (e.forEach && e.forEach !== S) e.forEach(t, n);
    else
        for (r in e) e.hasOwnProperty(r) && t.call(n, e[r], r);
    return e
}
```

"

The code is works fine before being compiled, concatened and minified.

Anyone have any advice on what to try to do to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tough error because it get's into the nuance of browser specific implementations of ECMAScript.  Here's a quick breakdown if you are interested: [ES5 Strict Mode Requirements](http://whereswalden.com/2011/01/24/new-es5-strict-mode-requirement-function-statements-not-at-top-level-of-a-program-or-function-are-prohibited/).

The error essentially breaks down to the fact that a function is being declared where it shouldn't be.  This is often just "handled" by the browser, but moving forward (and in `strict mode`) the browser will stop helping with this and simply throw an error.  The simple solution to this is to never declare a function without assigning it to a local variable. `let fn = function(){...}` rather than `function fn(){...}`.  You still use the function the same [ex: `var a = fn()`], but it is now tied to the scope of the variable you assigned it to.  This makes it easier to comprehend and debug because it follows the same rules as any other variable declaration.  It is undefined until it has been declared (so don't call it before it is declared), it is only usable within it's scope (so if you declare it inside a function, it is only available within that function), and it can be overwritten or changed at any time.

I do not see the error being thrown from the code you posted, so it is likely occurring somewhere deeper down in this module.  Would you be able to post the full file?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.

Basically I prettified the js and discovered that some added code was indeed function declarations inside an if statement.

I was not familiar with this demand of use strict, especially since I am not that used to using strict and this someone elses code I am working on.